# How can i get class properties name in class decorator?

Tags: javascript, typescript

It is possible to get class properties and there types in class decorator?

maybe by reflection?

```
function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        // this.props.forEach(p => log(p.type)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a class that you're trying to decorate and then point out which details of that class you're trying to access in the decorator?

Comment: class a{x:number;y:string;z} - how to get x,y,z and there type. without doing prop initials.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904456/how-to-iterate-over-non-existent-member-of-a-class